Get if template is a function, function pointer or lambda?
As the title says, I'm trying to get wether my template argument is or is not a lambda.
std::is_function exists, as std::is_class (lambdas are considered classes) and std::is_pointer do, but obviously if someone inputs an actual class into the function, it should throw some error. How can I do this?

Why do you feel the need to know this?  Also, show us your template please.

The only thing special about a closure (an object defined by a lambda expression) is how it is defined and that it is anonymous. I can't think of any characteristic that couldn't be replicated by normal user defined function object. Why is it important to know if a type is a closure or not?

It is not possible because a lambda can not be distinguished from a function object.

what does it mean for you that you get a lambda passed? Make that explicit, specify it, in the question. Then we can help you to write a trait. Though that trait will also match other things that match your notion of what makes a lambda. A lambda is just an instance of some custom type like any others like you could also write

A lambda is syntactic sugar for a perfectly regular object, so no, you can't do that.

In addition to aforementioned problems, non-capturing lambda's can be converted to function pointers. What are you really trying to solve here? Also, see std::invocable.

You can't tell a lambda apart from an object of a class type because that's exactly what a lambda is.  A lambda expression is just a short-hand notation for defining an object of an anonymous class type that has an overloaded operator().
For example, the following lambda:
int i = 2;
std::string s = "hello";
auto short_form = [i, &s](int param) { return s + std::to_string(i * param); };

is exactly equivalent to the following class:
class anonymous
{
    int i;
    std::string& s;

public:
    anonymous(int i, std::string& s) : i{i}, s{s} {}

    auto operator()(int param) const
    {
        return s + std::to_string(i * param);
    }
} long_form(i, s);

Demo

Note: Non-capturing lambdas are a bit more complex, since they need to be implicitly-convertible to a normal function pointer.  They are still objects of a class type with an overloaded operator(), but they have some extra functionality as well.
